# python linspace in c++

Tags: python, c++, numpy

im trying to write a similar version of python's numpy.linspace function.

```
double linspace(int a, int b, int c){
    double line[c];
    double delta =b-a/(c-1);
    for (int i=0; i<c; ++i){
            line[i]=0 + (i*delta);
    }
    return line;
```

with a and b being the first and the last component in the array, and c specifying the number of elements in the array. But when i compile this script it returns:

```
linspace.cpp: In function ‘double linspace(int, int, int)’:
linspace.cpp:11:9: error: cannot convert ‘double*’ to ‘double’ in return
  return line;
         ^
```

would anyone happen to knw how to solve this problem?

Comment: Also, `b-a/(c-1)` (did you mean `(b-a)/(c-1)`?) is integer division.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169418/numpy-style-arrays-for-c) may be of interest. Summarizes a bunch of libraries that mimic numpy in c++.

Answer (score 26):

How about something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
std::vector<double> linspace(T start_in, T end_in, int num_in)
{

  std::vector<double> linspaced;

  double start = static_cast<double>(start_in);
  double end = static_cast<double>(end_in);
  double num = static_cast<double>(num_in);

  if (num == 0) { return linspaced; }
  if (num == 1) 
    {
      linspaced.push_back(start);
      return linspaced;
    }

  double delta = (end - start) / (num - 1);

  for(int i=0; i < num-1; ++i)
    {
      linspaced.push_back(start + delta * i);
    }
  linspaced.push_back(end); // I want to ensure that start and end
                            // are exactly the same as the input
  return linspaced;
}

void print_vector(std::vector<double> vec)
{
  std::cout << "size: " << vec.size() << std::endl;
  for (double d : vec)
    std::cout << d << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<double> vec_1 = linspace(1, 10, 3);
  print_vector(vec_1);

  std::vector<double> vec_2 = linspace(6.0, 23.4, 5);
  print_vector(vec_2);

  std::vector<double> vec_3 = linspace(0.0, 2.0, 1);
  print_vector(vec_3);

  std::vector<double> vec_4 = linspace(0.0, 2.0, 0);
  print_vector(vec_4);


  return 0;
}
```

C++ result:

```
size: 3
1 5.5 10 
size: 5
6 10.35 14.7 19.05 23.4 
size: 1
0 
size: 0
```

Numpy result:

```
In [14]: np.linspace(1, 10, 3)
Out[14]: array([  1. ,   5.5,  10. ])

In [15]: np.linspace(6, 23.4, 5)
Out[15]: array([  6.  ,  10.35,  14.7 ,  19.05,  23.4 ])

In [16]: np.linspace(0.0, 2.0, 1)
Out[16]: array([ 0.])

In [17]: np.linspace(0.0, 2.0, 0)
Out[17]: array([], dtype=float64)
```

Comment: Your template fails for me, I copied it verbatim, and get an out of range-error for the vector.

Comment: @arc_lupus. Thank You for pointing this out! I believe I fixed it. I compiled it like this and it worked correctly: `g++ -std=c++11 my_file.cpp -o my_exec`.

Comment: I had to remove the 'linspaced.push_back(end);' command as it was making 'end_in' appear two times.

Comment: @PedroH.N.Vieira, thank you for pointing this out. I will take a look at it. Do you have sample input, so I can reproduce the issue?

Comment: It appeared when I called 'linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 21)'

Comment: @PedroH.N.Vieira, It was quite easy to reproduce. I fixed it. Thanks again for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do what won't work.  First off you are allocating the memory on the stack WITHIN `linspace` with

```
double line[c];
```

You either new to allocate the memory before the call and pass it in, or allocate it dynamically and return it (and remember to free it later).

To allocate dynamically you can do the following:

```
double * line = new double[c];
```

Again, this will need to be freed like so at some point later when you are finished with it, otherwise you will have a memory leak.

```
delete line[];
```

Also `double line[c];` creates an array of doubles and `line` points to that.  So line is a `double *`.  You specified the return type of the function as `double`

Comment: An example of what?  If you change `double line[c];` to 'double * line = new double[c];` and change the return type of the function you are done.  Whenever you are done with the data, whatever is returned from this function needs to be deleted.  So... `double * lin_ret = linspace(a,b,c);` After you are done with `lin_ret` do `delete lin_ret[];`

Comment: Ha! An *asker* requesting an example! That's rich.

Comment: You really should use a vector for this rather than naked `new`.